# How to find out who is restoring the database in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am the admin and i have not touched that database but all of a sudden it shows like someone is restoring it since long

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running `EXECUTE sp_who2` to identify the process that is running the restore. That row will also display who is doing it and from which machine.

Comment: Thanks for the ans, it didnt solve completely but helped me in solving it

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
SELECT [USER_NAME] 
      ,restore_date
      ,destination_database_name
FROM msdb..restorehistory
WHERE destination_database_name = 'DB_Name'   --<-- Your Database name
```

Comment: I tried it it just shows the last restore details, i am trying to find the current restore details

Answer (score 1):

It's too late for you, but I'd use something like this:

```
select s.original_login_name
from sys.dm_exec_requests as r
join sys.dm_exec_sessions as s
   on r.session_id = s.session_id
where r.command = 'RESTORE'
```